# What information do I need to know before starting DC's Flashpoint arc?

Tags: dc, batman, suggested-order, flashpoint, blackest-night

I'm almost through reading *Blackest Night* and will read *Brightest Day* right after.

I'm not really interested in reading the next event *Batman: The Return of Bruce Wayne* and want to skip right to *FlashPoint*. What information is learned in *Return of Bruce Wayne* that may be vital to the story line of *Flashpoint*, if anything?

I'm assuming that Batman returns from the dead or something as he's dead in *Blackest Night*. So, that's obvious (or is it **too** obvious??). But is there anything else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing from *Return of Bruce Wayne* should impact too heavily on *FlashPoint*. *FlashPoint* stands as the precursor to *The New 52*.

A basic knowledge of the DC Universe as a whole prior to *The New 52* would help in both the core series and tie-in stories, just so you can understand the differences that happened.

Also, basic knowledge of [The Flash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Flash) and [The Reverse Flash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Professor_Zoom) would be good enough for the core series of *FlashPoint*. (Note: Avoid the *FlashPoint* sections in the above links for obvious spoiler reasons)